# Pixelate math formula on purpose

Tags: fonts, pixelated

AFAIK the standard pdf documents produced by pdflatex are mostly vectorized (you can zoom and it doesn't pixelate).

That is a very good thing, but right now I would like the oposite: is it possible to "pixelate" the whole document (text and math equations) so that the output pdf looks like it was generated by a 8-bit computer? (while still being readable)

Thanks.

Comment: Well you always can convert every page to a png and insert this in another document. But beside this it depends on the fonts used. If you are using the standard computer modern fonts you can disable the map-file and then latex will use pk-fonts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As Ulrike mentioned in her comment, you could remove the map file to get the old bitmap font loaded instead of vector fonts.

```
\pdfmapfile{-pdftex.map}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a + b = c$
\end{document}
```

No sure whether this is pixelated enough for you.

[image]

To get it even more pixelated, just crank down `\pdfpkresolution` (thanks  Thérèse!)

```
\pdfmapfile{-pdftex.map}
\pdfpkresolution=100 % default 600
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$a + b = c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Otherwise you could just look for a font which has the desired effect online, like from here https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/pixel.  For example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{VT323-Regular.ttf}
\setmathfont{Latin Modern Math}
\setmathfont[range=it->up]{VT323-Regular.ttf}
\setmathfont[range=]{Latin Modern Math}
\begin{document}
$a + b = c$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If the O.P. wants it more pixelated, adding `\pdfpkresolution=100` or some other low number to the preamble will do the trick.